# On List Click > Get Root UL ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

My list looks like this;

```
<ul id="SiteNav" class="Mail New">
    <li class="Send"><a href="javascript:;" data-action="mail-send">Send</a></li>
    <li class="Insert">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="Drop">Insert <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-action="mail-files-as-attachments">Files as attachments</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-action="mail-pictures-inline">Pictures inline</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" data-action="mail-share-from-BananzaCloud">Share from BananzaCloud</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

And then my script starts with;

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {
```

On all links clicked on this menu, I want to check if the $(e.target) is a child of `id="SiteNav"`

Comment: `$(document).on('mousedown', '#SiteNav', function(e) {`

Comment: @Rayon SiteNav is an id not a class so this will not work

Comment: @Mivaweb, Edited! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen all document mouse down events, and filter those based on event target.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(e) {

        if ($(e.target).parents('#SiteNav').length){

          //your code
        }
    })
```

or a better approach to listen directly on the menu container

```
$('#SiteNav a').on('mousedown', function(e) {
console.log('test');
})
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your code so that the OP understands what you are doing!

Comment: Will this work regardless of how many levels my menu reaches? And thank you @Mivaweb

Comment: `if ($(e.target).parents('#SiteNav').length){` works perfect for what I need to do, thank you